# Looking for a callback for when MapBox map tiles are loaded (iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, mapbox

I am looking for a callback to check if all map tiles were loaded after requesting it? I am using the MapBox SDK for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exist yet, but it is being tracked in the project's issue queue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/issues/236

You are welcome to take a crack at it, too, since it's open source, but otherwise, you will find any updates there.

Comment: on the github issues you are mentioning the "NSNotification" object, would that be a place to start with? and what would be the notification string to listen for?

Comment: Currently I'm not entirely sure if the notifications are hooked up properly. Since the tile filling-in is done by `CATiledLayer`, you don't have insight into whether all the tiles are loaded or not directly. You would probably have to keep track of tile load starts in `RMMapTiledLayer` and then as long as zoom or pan doesn't change, consider things done when all of those have completed.